# Winform in unity is not displaying as it should

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm facing a problem with displaying a Winform I've created in the unity editor, for some reason the form is not displaying as it should in the unity editor...

- most controls in the form have the "autosize" property set to true
  and the "autoSizeMode" property set to "GrowAndShrink". and whenever
  I display the form in the unity editor, these controls just vanish..
  their size is set to (0,0) regardless of the inner controls they
  hold. (setting manually the "minimumSize" property of these controls does makes them visible again.)
- the "sutoScroll" property is not displaying the sliders.
- the "dock" property is not acting as it should.

some of the majors I've taken:

1. I've added the **right** dlls (such as the "system.windows.forms.dll) to the unity project.

   I've merged the ".cs" and ".designer.cs" of each form into a single file, so I won't face this problem "[Form and designer files not linking in Solution Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599843/form-and-designer-files-not-linking-in-solution-explorer)", and I copied them to the unity project.
2. I've tried making a "class library" project and copy the forms into it.
   placing the build/debug dll in the unity project and displaying the form. (still the same result though)
3. I've copied the ".exe" of the winform project to unity, and
   calling/displaying the exe does show the form correctly, but I want
   to be able to share collection references between the exe and unity
   editor... and from what I've read online don't think it's passable ..

any suggestions on how to resolve the issue? or no how to display a Winform in unity editor without it getting all messed up, and share argument references between the both?

this is an image of the winform running in visual studio:

[image: img1]

this is an image of the form displayed through unity:

[image: img2]

[this is a link to the Winform project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fUjyVx1SaVr0YVJ4Qp5s7eNMxZ1Gd4bm/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You are trying to use Winform in Unity? The game engine?

Comment: yeah, but as a plugin to the engine and not an in-game thing

Comment: Unitiy has it's own [UI system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/gui-Basics.html) for plugins for the engine, you need to use those controls, not winforms. see also https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html

Comment: thanks, I do know that already, and I did use it before to build other plugins. but building a form/GUI in winforms is way simpler and faster than using the custom unity editor, and that's why I'm asking if there's a way import a winform to unity.

Comment: Mono WinForms is an incomplete technology. Give it up and go back to the right track as others commented.

Comment: I was trying to confirm that you this is actually what you are trying to do. Don't attempt to do this because it will only work on Windows OS. This removes the main reason of using Unity which is to build your app for mobile devices and other platforms. Learn Unity UI.

Comment: @Programmer it shouldn't affect the games/final product as it is a tool used only inside the editor

Comment: @LexLi it's really annoying though :/ ... anyways thanks, it's probably what I'll end up doing.

Comment: IMGUI Mentioned by scott is part of Unity. That's made for building tools in the Editor.